# DRAM - is data pins order important when routing on PCB?

Tags: pcb, pins, ram, data, sdram

Quick question: I have SDRAM (SDR) and trying to connect it to uC.

Can I route data bits from SDRAM to uC in any order? So they aren't connected respectively (d0->d0, d1->d2 ... d15->d15) but in any order (like d0->d5, d1->d13 etc)?

If I understand correctly it shouldn't matter - if I write in that order and read in the same it should be ok. Am I right?

(I know that it doesn't apply to address bus because of burst-read, columns/rows etc).

Comment: Yes, it should be OK.

Comment: It should be OK, but a bit confusing. And very confusing if something is going wrong and someone to debug it. Or if you decide to put some other stuff on that bus (like DMA controller).

Comment: Usually there is an onboard memory controller and the ability to remap data lines can be limited. It is probably doable but adds unnecessary confusion and complication.

Comment: Unless the RAM chip has some less common signature or locking features that require you to write specific (out of band) signature data to it (that it is expecting the way it is in the datasheet) there is no way for the RAM to know what data you put in and so the same will come out. Mixing with other chips on the bus or externally preprogrammed chips does get interesting though as the EPROM programmer will be 1 to 1 map.

Comment: When connecting Flash or otherwise ROM devices you might want to think twice as you would have to convert it contents before programming it.

Comment: However, don't swap the address lines. Or if you really must, rewrite the "Load Mode Register" part of the initialisation sequence to match...

Comment: I think you need to keep each byte-worth of data lines together as they are masked by the DQM lines. So you could exchange D0 with D1 through D7 but not D8 through D15.

Comment: @BrianDrummond brings up an interesting point. I am not sure what "Load Mode Register" does, maybe I'm typing about the same thing: I remember from many years ago that subsequent (incremental) reads from RAM are much faster than true random accesses. Not sure if this is still the case today.

Comment: I know about address lines (as I wrote in my first post) and subsequent readis still faster.
Good point DoxyLover, I've forgotten about DQM lines. By the way, why there is this DQM masking? It always confuses me.
And what you say doesn't apply for SRAM?

Comment: Mode register uses the address bits to set burst length, some internal delay, and (I think) enable/disable the clock DLL. Details are all in the DRAM's datasheet.

Comment: DQM lines are the byte enables for writes.  If the memory chip has an interface that is more than 8 bits wide, the DQM lines allow writes to be selectively enabled on groups of 8 lines so you can do writes of less than a full word size without having to do a read-modify-write operation.

Comment: Thank you alex.forencich yesterday that's what I thought, but I'm more unsure about this: if I always want to read and write 16 bits I can just not use those DQM?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you keep the association with the byte enables correct.  There should be no issue with switching around data lines within each byte or mixing up the bytes, so long as you keep track of the byte enables.  However, it would be a good idea to check the datasheet to make sure there aren't any odd requirements with respect to bursts or accessing internal control registers.  Also, you might be able to switch around some address lines, but you should keep the low order address lines un-swapped so that sequential accesses don't incur timing penalties.  Also, make sure you don't switch around address lines that correspond to configuration commands, or at least keep track of what got swapped so you can send the right command to the chip.